# openerp wizard is calling base res.partner form instead of mine

Tags: python, crm, odoo, erp

Hi I have inherited the CRM module. I inherited the customer model and override redirect_partner_form as

```
from osv import fields, osv
from IPython.Debugger import Tracer; debug_here = Tracer()
class worldcable_customer(osv.osv):
   _name = "res.partner"
   _description = "worldcable customer"
   _inherit =  "res.partner"
   _columns = {
    'id': fields.integer('ID', readonly=True),
    'connection_info': fields.one2many('worldcable.connection.info', 'partner_id', 'Connection Info'),
    }

    def redirect_partner_form(self, cr, uid, partner_id, context=None):
        debug_here()
        search_view = self.pool.get('ir.model.data').get_object_reference(cr, uid, 'worldcable2',   'view_worldcable_customer_form')
    value = {
        'domain': "[]",
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_mode': 'form,tree',
        'res_model': 'res.partner',
        'res_id': int(partner_id),
        'view_id': False,
        'context': context,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'search_view_id': search_view and search_view[1] or False
    }
    debug_here()
    return value
    worldcable_customer()
```

and calling it in wizard ,

```
from osv import osv, fields
from tools.translate import _
class crm_lead2partner(osv.osv_memory):
""" Converts lead to partner """
_name = 'worldcable.crm.connection2partner'
_description = 'Connection to Partner'

_columns = {
    'action': fields.selection([('exist', 'Link to an existing partner'), \
                                ('create', 'Create a new partner')], \
                                'Action', required=True),
    'partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Partner'),
}
def view_init(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    """
    This function checks for precondition before wizard executes
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    model = context.get('active_model')
    model = self.pool.get(model)
    rec_ids = context and context.get('active_ids', [])
    for this in model.browse(cr, uid, rec_ids, context=context):
        if this.partner_id:
            raise osv.except_osv(_('Warning !'),
                    _('A partner is already defined.'))

def _select_partner(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    lead = self.pool.get('crm.lead')
    partner = self.pool.get('res.partner')
    lead_ids = list(context and context.get('active_ids', []) or [])
    if not len(lead_ids):
        return False
    this = lead.browse(cr, uid, lead_ids[0], context=context)
    # Find partner address matches the email_from of the lead
    res = lead.message_partner_by_email(cr, uid, this.email_from, context=context)
    partner_id = res.get('partner_id', False)      
    # Find partner name that matches the name of the lead
    if not partner_id and this.partner_name:
        partner_ids = partner.search(cr, uid, [('name', '=', this.partner_name)], context=context)
        if partner_ids and len(partner_ids):
           partner_id = partner_ids[0]
    return partner_id

def default_get(self, cr, uid, fields, context=None):
    """
    This function gets default values
    """
    res = super(crm_lead2partner, self).default_get(cr, uid, fields, context=context)        
    partner_id = self._select_partner(cr, uid, context=context)

    if 'partner_id' in fields:
        res.update({'partner_id': partner_id})
    if 'action' in fields:
        res.update({'action': partner_id and 'exist' or 'create'})

    return res

def open_create_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    This function Opens form of create partner.
    """
    view_obj = self.pool.get('ir.ui.view')
    view_id = view_obj.search(cr, uid, [('model', '=', self._name), \
                                 ('name', '=', self._name+'.view')])
    return {
        'view_mode': 'form',
        'view_type': 'form',
        'view_id': view_id or False,
        'res_model': self._name,
        'context': context,
        'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
        'target': 'new',
    }

def _create_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    This function Creates partner based on action.
    """
    if context is None:
        context = {}
    lead = self.pool.get('crm.lead')
    lead_ids = context and context.get('active_ids') or []
    data = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)[0]
    partner_id = data.partner_id and data.partner_id.id or False
    return lead.convert_partner(cr, uid, lead_ids, data.action, partner_id, context=context)

def make_partner(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    """
    This function Makes partner based on action.
    """
    # Only called from Form view, so only meant to convert  one Lead. 
    lead_id = context and context.get('active_id') or False
    partner_ids_map = self._create_partner(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    return self.pool.get('res.partner').redirect_partner_form(cr, uid, partner_ids_map.get(lead_id,  False), context=context)

crm_lead2partner()
```

but its calling original form from Base res.partner. I have checked the search_view_id from db, the id is same for my view. But I dont know whats an error. But surprisingly when I see the response to client, its like and is returning the connection_info table , means it is calling my view. But I dont know why it is showing res.partner form from base.

```
DEBUG_RPC_ANSWER:rpc.result:{'domain': '[]', 'view_type': 'form', 'res_model': 'res.partner',   'view_id': False, 'views': [(False, 'tree'), (57L, 'form')], 'search_view_id': 710, 'view_mode': 'form,tree', 'res_id': 57, 'context': {'lang': u'en_US', 'tz': False, 'active_model': 'crm.lead', 'section_id': False, 'search_default_current': 1, 'active_ids': [35L], 'active_id': 35L}, 'type': 'ir.actions.act_window'}
```

I thing I have noted that there is an error of address in it

```
ERROR:tools.expr_eval:{'address': address}
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/noaman/projects/openerp/repository-openerp/Sid/client/bin/tools/__init__.py", line 52,  in   expr_eval
temp = eval(string, context)
File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'address' is not defined
```

my customer xml is as follow

```
<openerp>
<data>
<record model="ir.ui.view" id="view_worldcable_customer_form">
        <field name="name">worldcable.partner.form</field>
        <field name="model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="type">form</field>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <form string="Worldcable Customers" col='1'>
                <group col="6" colspan="4">
                    <group colspan="5" col="6">
                        <field name="name" select="1"/>
                        <field name="ref" groups="base.group_extended"/>
                        <field domain="[('domain', '=', 'partner')]" name="title" size="0"  groups="base.group_extended"/>
                        <field name="lang"/>
                    </group>
                    <group colspan="1" col="2">
                        <field name="customer" select="1" readonly="1"/>
                         <!--                            <field name="employee"/>-->
                    </group>
                </group>
                <notebook colspan="4">
                    <page string="Connection Info">
                     <field colspan="4" mode="form,tree" name="connection_info" nolabel="1" select="1" height="260">
                        <form string="Connection Info">
                            <group colspan="4" col="4">
                                <field name="mac_address"/>
                                <field name="telephone_no"/>
                                <field name="tv_provider"/>
                                <field name="internet_provider"/>
                                <field name="phone_provider"/>
                                <field name="circuit_id"/>                                    
                                <field name="iigo_number"/>
                                <field name="dsl_no"/>
                                <field name="exchange"/>
                                <field name="service_type"/>   
                            </group>
                        </form>
                        <tree string="Connection Info">
                            <field name="mac_address"/>
                            <field name="circuit_id"/>
                            <field name="iigo_number"/>
                            <field name="dsl_no"/>
                            <field name="exchange"/>
                            <field name="tv_provider"/>
                            <field name="phone_provider"/>
                            <field name="internet_provider"/>
                        </tree>                            
                     </field>
                    </page>
                    <page string="General">
                        <field colspan="4" mode="form,tree" name="address" nolabel="1" select="1" height="260">
                            <form string="Partner Contacts">
                                <group colspan="4" col="6">
                                    <field domain="[('domain', '=', 'contact')]" name="title" size="0"/>
                                    <field name="first_name" colspan="2" string="First Name"/>
                                    <field name="middle_name" colspan="1" string="Middle Name"/>
                                    <field name="last_name" colspan="1" string="Last Name"/>   
                                </group>
                                <newline/>
                                <group colspan="2" col="4">

                                    <separator string="Postal Address" colspan="4" col="4" />
                                    <field name="type" string="Type" colspan="2"/>
                                    <field name="floor" colspan="2"/>
                                    <field name="zip"/>
                                    <field name="street" colspan="4"/>
                                    <field name="street2" colspan="4"/>
                                    <field name= "apartment" colspan="2"/>
                                    <field name="city"/>
                                    <field name="state_id"/>
                                    <field name="country_id" completion="1"/>
                                </group>
                                <group colspan="2" col="2">
                                    <separator string="Communication" colspan="2" col="2" />
                                    <field name="phone"/>
                                    <field name="mobile"/>
                                    <field name ="other_no"/>
                                    <field name="fax"/>
                                    <field name="email" widget="email"/>
                                </group>
                            </form>
                            <tree string="Partner Contacts">
                                <field name="name"/>
                                <field name="zip"/>
                                <field name="city"/>
                                <field name="country_id"/>
                                <field name="phone"/>
                                <field name="email"/>
                            </tree>
                        </field>
                    </page>
                    <page string="Sales &amp; Purchases">
                        <separator string="General Information" colspan="4"/>
                        <field name="user_id"/>
                        <field name="active" groups="base.group_extended"/>
                        <field name="website" widget="url"/>
                        <field name="date"/>
                        <field name="parent_id" groups="base.group_extended"/>
                        <field name="company_id" groups="base.group_multi_company" widget="selection"/>
                        <newline/>
                    </page>
                    <page string="History" groups="base.group_extended" invisible="True">
                    </page>
                    <page string="Notes">
                        <field colspan="4" name="comment" nolabel="1"/>
                    </page>

                </notebook>
            </form>
        </field>
  </record>
  <record id="act_my_worldcable_customer_form" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Worldcable Customer</field>
        <field name="res_model">res.partner</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_mode">tree,calendar,form</field>
        <field name="context">{'search_default_current':1}</field>
        <field name="help">Worldcable Customer Search</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="view_worldcable_customer_form"/>
  </record>
  <menuitem id="menu_myview_worldcable_customer" parent="base.myview_menu" name="Customers" icon="terp-partner" action="act_my_worldcable_customer_form" groups="base.group_extended,base.group_sale_salesman" sequence="2"/>
 </data>
 </openerp>
```

Can somebody help me , how may I call my form instead of base form. I have tried all ways.
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I assume there was an error in your copy/paste in the first code block, as the line indents are wrong starting with the line with the `value` assignation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `search_view_id` field in an action definition is used to specify the **`search`** view to use, not the **`form`** view, as the name implies. If you want to use a specific form view you should use the `view_id` field instead (which is used to specify the main view to open, typically a `form` or `tree` one).
And by the way all the view selection fields in an OpenERP action definition may be overridden by specifying a `views` field: an ordered list of pairs `(view_id, view_mode)` where `view_id` can be `False` to use the default view. This is a computed field that the framework automatically adds on regular actions, but may be manually added to a custom action returned by a Python method.

Here is how you could do it in a Python method:

```
# assuming partner_id, context, form_view_id are defined here
return {
    'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
    'view_type': 'form',
    'view_mode': 'form,tree',
    'res_model': 'res.partner',
    'res_id': int(partner_id),
    'context': context,
    'view_id': form_view_id, 

    # optionally, you could refine by specifying the 'views' explicitly
    'views': [(form_view_id, 'form'),  # open my form view first,
              (False, 'tree')]         # then default tree view
}
```

You will find a lot of similar examples in the source code of the official addons, search for code returning `'views'` or `'view_id'`.

Now there are side questions related to what you are trying to do, and you probably want to answer them in addition to solving your immediate issue.

1. The easiest way to modify an existing view in OpenERP is to inherit it. At first look it seems you're just trying to a new tab "Connection Info" on the partner form view. It would be trivial (and a lot simpler) to simply create an inherited view that hooks to the `<notebook>` element of the parent view and add an extra `<page>` in it. And if you don't want the tab to be shown in all situations, you can add visibility modifiers to the page with a special `attrs` attribute.
   Hence the question: why don't you use this technique here?
2. When you don't want to inherit an existing view (because the new view is totally different), the second easiest method is to create a new view of the same type and give it a higher priority (lower `priority` field value). This will automatically replace the default view everywhere this view type is needed. The only cases were it doesn't work is when a specific view_id is requested by the action that opens the view.
   It seems you could do it here, so the second question is: why not use this other technique here?

Comment: Hi thanks its solved by your first technique. I am surprised that return value dictionary explanation is not in anywhere. Now the answers for your points I want to tell you that I am totally newbie in openerp. I did not do these techniques because I dont want to touch original module. For example if inherit view or change its priority , even in original CRM module will show my forms. Which I think is not good practice. Anyway you saved my many days. Thanks again from the depth of my heart.